# Overriding list and Java practice

Tags: java, list

I have three classes (The number will be probably grow in the future):

```
public inteface Base{ }

public class Select implements Base{ }

public class Ast implements Base{ }

public class Gt implements Base{ }
```

I also need in a `List` class

```
BaseList extends ArrayList<Base>{
    public boolean add(Base b){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You should use add%ConcereteBaseType% method instead");
    }

    public boolean add(Select s){ }

    public boolean add(Ast a){ }

    public boolean add(Gt g){ }
}
```

The reason why I did this was the fact that I don't want anyone to adds elements via a pointer to `Base`. In my concrete situation this would be unsafe.

But the disadvantage is that it will be discovered only at runtime.

I also need to iterate over the list.

Is it a good practice to do such things?

Comment: It's more likely that all this is misuse of inheritance.  I'd bet that whatever you have in mind could be accomplished with composition.

Comment: @duffymo Maybe you can give an example to understand things youre talkiung about?

Comment: "Composition" means having an `ArrayList` as a field rather than extending an `ArrayList`. (See my or memberssound's answer for example code.)

Comment: @St.Antario I think duffymo's concern of commenting is providing separate overloaded version of add( implementation of child of Base) is avoiding the advantage of inheritence.

Comment: If `add(x)` is unsafe, then is `if(x instanceof Select) add((Select)x); else if(x instanceof Ast) add((Ast)x); else if(x instanceof Gt) add((Gt)x);` also unsafe?

Comment: @St.Antario okay.  My thought is that these List subclasses won't be used in isolation; they're part of a larger abstraction.  Let that be the thing that controls access to its data member.  "Disadvantage....discovered only at runtime" - that's the beauty of polymorphism.  You shouldn't have to know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using an `interface` is fine. (Turning `Base` into an abstract class won't buy you anything here.)

You should favor composition over inheritance here though, and implement `Iterable<Base>` to be able to use it in enhanced for loops etc.

```
class BaseList implements Iterable<Base> {
    private List<Base> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean add(Select s) {
        return list.add(s);
    }

    public boolean add(Ast a) {
        return list.add(a);
    }

    public boolean add(Gt gt) {
        return list.add(gt);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Base> iterator() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list).iterator();
    }
}
```

You can then iterate over the list as follows:

```
for (Base b : yourBaseList) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: using 'Collections.unmodifiableList(list).iterator()' restrict this iterator only for traversing purpose.why should it required?this seems like unnecessary restriction to mitigate the power and benefits of 'Iterator'.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcortians, granted this is a matter of design, and it's not necessarily the right thing to do. It increases the encapsulation though, so it's the defensive thing to do here. If OP chooses to add a `remove` method to `BaseList` for instance, the `unmodifiableList` should definitely be dropped.

Answer (score 7):

You could make `Base` an `abstract` class, as these could never be instantiated, your list would be safe.

My the way: I really don't understand why you would like to throw an exception for `add(Base b)` when base is an `interface` which itself can never be an object.

Otherwise, use delegate/wrapper pattern, means: Do not extend `ArrayList`, but create a class *holding* an ArrayList.

```
class BaseList {
    private List<Base> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean add(Select s) {
         return list.add(s);
    }
    //etc
}
```

Comment: re: first point, you could still instantiate a subclass, but have a reference of type `Base`. Using delegate - right on, good suggestion.

Comment: I don't see how making `Base` an abstract class would make any difference. The same rules regarding instantiation applies to interfaces as well.

Comment: But I won't be able to iterate over BaseList with foreach loop then. That's not very good.

Comment: Why not? You can iterate over any list that is a `List`.

Comment: Sure you can. Either add a `List<Base> getList()` method (returning un unmodifiable view of the list) to the class and iterate on the list, or make your class implement `Iterable<Base>`, by returning the list iterator.

Comment: If `BaseList` implements `Iterable`, you can iterate it with a foreach too.

Comment: As the class is by design a delegate/wrapper class, you of course have to also delegate the iteration to the list, as pointed out above using the `Iterable` interface.

Comment: @JBNizet So I can use foreach loop __iff__ the class implements `Iterable`?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html says: *Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement.*

Comment: @St.Antario "*So I can use foreach loop iff the class implements Iterable*" it is true only if you are asking only classes. But lets not forget that beside instances of `Iterable` we can also use foreach loop to iterate over arrays (which are not implementation of `Iterable`).